# How do I implement 'Go To Definition' type of functionality based on LSP for project with huge amount of files?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Is there a recommended approach for LSP implementation?

As I understand, I need to read/index all files on the background and store all kinds of declarations in memory.

List of examples: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers
LSP Server is written on nodejs + typescript

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. It obviously depends on the language, for some it may be possible to implement something like go to declaration without indexing everything. But usually you'd need to anyway because of other features like completion and workspace symbols.

Comment: @Gama11 yes, you are right. Various data should be available and cached to support this kind of features.